# DM Force SSL based on Stash not_empty variable

Tags: stash, ssl

Somehow I can't seem to get this right. I have a Stash variable that I'm setting if certain pages need to be redirected to their HTTPS version.

Tried it a number of ways, but very similar to this:

```
{if {exp:stash:not_empty name="secure" parse="inward" process="inline"} == 1 }
      {exp:dm_force_ssl:force parse="inward"}
{/if}
```

This code resides in an embed btw (template partials approach, where the "secure" variable is set in the parent template partial, then the other variables are pushed into the wrapper). It ends up redirecting *every* page, not just the ones that fall into the conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up solving this with a combo of Switchee and Stash:

```
{exp:switchee variable="stash:secure" parse="inward"}
      {case value="y"}
        {exp:dm_force_ssl:force}
      {/case}
      {case value=""}
         {exp:dm_force_ssl:unforce}
      {/case}
{/exp:switchee}
```

Since Stash was used to set the "secure" variable, and Switchee is Stash-aware, you can just use the variable within Switchee.

Answer (score 0):

Try a couple different iterations of the conditional:

```
{if "{exp:stash:not_empty name="secure" parse="inward" process="inline"}" == "1" }

{if '{exp:stash:not_empty name="secure" parse="inward" process="inline"}' == '1' }

{if "1" == "{exp:stash:not_empty name="secure" parse="inward" process="inline"}"}

{if '1' == '{exp:stash:not_empty name="secure" parse="inward" process="inline"}'}
```

---

Also, `parse="inward"` most likely isn't needed on the `{exp:dm_force_ssl:force}` tag.

Comment: Nadda. Kinda wondering if a header redirect is parsed before Stash even inits...